# How can I fix "Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "xxx" already exist"?

Tags: magento-1.8, product, catalog, collection-filtering

I have been getting this error when trying to filter a products collection

`Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "6058" already exist` and wanted to ask what could ne causing the error since there is only one (visible) product with the same ID inside of Magento.

Is there a table that needs to be cleared to remove this dupilcate?

Comment: Can you add some code? You need to use `group by` to get  only unique product id. See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/item-mage-sales-model-order-with-the-same-id-x-already-exist

Comment: @R.S, Hi, I am still trying to find the cause I'll post back as soon as I track it down...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Adding the `distinct` as suggested in the accepted answer does fix the problem but it has performance issues. The database might create temporary tables on disk when executing a query with `distinct` and this will slow down your request. You can instead add a `group` condition to the collection to remove duplicates.

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120381/filter-product-collection-on-two-categories-magento-1-7). What they did (and I have done it also) is group by the entity id. This should perform better.

```
//adding filters to the collection..

$collection->getSelect()
           ->group('e.entity_id');
```

Comment: can you please tell where we need to add this code

Comment: @BabyinMagento wherever it is you're using your collection in your custom code. This error occurs when creating custom modules that fetch collections from the database. This means it could show up if you have installed third party modules recently. In that case, it is up to the developer of said module to find the location of the error.

Comment: The `distinct()` solution and this will remove any additional records from the query, which means you might lose data without noticing. So this might not be the best solution, as in my case. I'm now trying to find a way to get both the records from my joined table into the collection so that I can show both records on the same row in grid.

Comment: Little note: its importend to not chain this to the collection, but furst put your colelction to a variable and than do $collection->getSelect()
           ->group('e.entity_id');

Comment: where can i update this code?

Comment: @zus wherever it is you're using the collection in the code. If you haven't been working with collections in code, maybe this isn't your answer. This code usually happens when creating custom Magento modules, or editing existing modules.

Answer (score 10):

Normally, this is a bug in the data or in the collection implementation.

Here's a solution to a broader issue. This works on arbitrary collection, not only for `Catalog_Model_Product`.

Step 1. Modify the core file `lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php`, `function addItem()`, but unlike [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/63645/14177) suggests, don't hide the error.

Instead, add extra error information to the exception thrown:

```
        if (isset($this->_items[$itemId])) {
            throw new Exception('Item ('.get_class($item).
                ') with the same id "'.$item->getId().'" already exist' .
                '. SQL that caused this: ' . $this->getSelect());
        }
```

Step 2. Take the offending query from your error report and run it by hand. See what records duplicate the collection key. Add `order by <key field>` as needed.

Dissect the query removing the participating tables one-by-one, and see which record caused the duplication.

I believe this patch should be in the core.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Other answers had me thinking it was a bug in how Magento was building queries, but I felt uncomfortable with that all the solutions until I saw this. Dumped my select and saw that the bug was in how I built the query.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you have a collection (likely with a join or union) that is resulting in the same product being loaded into the collection twice.

You can alter the collection being loaded by adding a distinct method to the select object.

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html

```
$db->select()
         ->distinct()
```

But this comes with inherent problems. Using distinct will cause temporary tables to be created on disk, not in memory, which comes with performance penalties.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

not working i use:

```
->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');
```

Mat be hejpful for some one as well