# Item with the same id "2011" already exist

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I am getting this error when i try to sign in as a customer. 
What is the reason behind this. I checked there is no duplicate entry for the record id 2011.
See error in details here https://prnt.sc/skxonz

I am using MAgento 1.9.4.4.
Please help

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40884/how-can-i-fix-item-mage-catalog-model-product-with-the-same-id-xxx-already

Comment: Which solution in this should i prefer. the correct one has a comment saying this is not the correct way.

Comment: @MohitPatel any idea what should i do?

Comment: try to correct answer

Comment: Which ans?? this was not happening initially and i have not done any custom coding recently...this issue appeared all of a sudden.

Comment: try correct sign answer and more upvote answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108289/discussion-between-mohit-patel-and-nafisa).