# Fatal error on `prepareColumns` method

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, collection, grid, join

Getting fatal error on `Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "223" already exist`

Here `223` is my product Id

My `_prepareCollection()` Method

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $coll = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('name',array('neq'=>''))  
                ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code',$this->getRequest()->getParam('my_value'));


    $coll->getSelect()->join( array('order_item'=> 'mgnt_sales_flat_order_item'), 'order_item.product_id = e.entity_id', array('order_item.created_at as ocreated','order_item.qty_ordered as sales_units', 'order_item.row_total as sales_total' , 'order_item.discount_amount as discount', 'order_item.item_id as item_id' ) );
    $coll->getSelect()->join( array('order'=> 'mgnt_sales_flat_order'), 'order.entity_id = order_item.order_id', array('customer_name'=>'order.customer_firstname'));



     $this->setCollection($coll);

    // echo $coll->getSelect(); 

     return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

My `_prepareColumns()` method

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{ 


    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
        'header' => $this->_getHelper()->__('entity_id'),
        'type' => 'text',
        'index' => 'entity_id',
        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false
    ));
    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => $this->_getHelper()->__('Product Name'),
        'type' => 'text',
        'index' => 'name',
        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false
    ));

    $this->addColumn('customer_name', array(
        'header' => $this->_getHelper()->__('customer_name'),
        'type' => 'number',
        'index' => 'customer_name',
        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false
    ));
    $this->addColumn('sales_total', array(
        'header' => $this->_getHelper()->__('Sales Total'),
        'type' => 'number',
        'index' => 'sales_total',
        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false
    ));
    $this->addColumn('discount', array(
        'header' => $this->_getHelper()->__('Discount'),
        'type' => 'number',
        'index' => 'discount',
        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false
    ));



    return parent::_prepareColumns();

}
```

Comment: Your collection in okay. check the database if there is any duplicate product Id.

Comment: @PrasantaHatui  nup I echo `$coll->getSelect()` any query seems to okay what I think this collection then in my result product id repetet so I think that might be issue

Comment: try grouping with product ID,  `$coll->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');`

Comment: @JaiminSutariya I dont wanna use `groupby` if there is 100 records with same `entity_id` then I dont have a problem because that is on `order_item` basis

Comment: If you can add details about what you want to achieve here?

Comment: @JaiminSutariya I want to filter product on some attribute basis and want to see how many order were there and who has order that order and when

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/12774/45103

Comment: Thanks @GopalPatel that link help me to understand why this error is occured

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per gopal's suggested link "You added something to the collection, which adds duplicates to the query result. What magento does with the query result is, to generate object from each row and then add these items to the collection. If the item already exists, this error is thrown."

As an hack you can try this for solution in your `_prepareCollection()` method:

```
$resource       = Mage::getModel('core/resource');
$connection     = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$sql            = $coll->getSelect();
$rows           = $connection->fetchAll($sql);//this row will return an array

    $collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $rowObj = new Varien_Object();
        $rowObj->setData($row);
        $collection->addItem($rowObj);
    }

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
```

Comment: Yeah big thumps up for conversion flow (collection to array and then to object) .  Actually i was thinking this step but not thought array as middle ware